# What is the name of the power which allows one to know future in dreams?

Tags: dream, siddhi

What is the name of the power which allows one to know future in dreams? One of my relatives say they can see future in their dreams.

Is this a spiritual gift? What is its name? What practices and karma in previous lives could have given them such abilities?

Comment: This is something I have read in Tantra books .. you have to do some sadhana dedicated towards some Goddess and she comes and discloses to you the future in your dream if the sadhana is a success

Comment: According to the person, it was not like that, there was no goddess involved, it was just a dream showing future events. They got this more than once.

Comment: Okay then I don't know what it was and how that faculty is achieved .. but in Tantras there is some sadhana through which one can know future in dreams